# Symfo2 - fm_elfinderbundle + IvoryCkeditorBundle Intégration

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, elfinder

I'm trying to integrate **elfinderbundle** with **ivoryCkeditorbundle** and it works!

However, when I try to upload an image, I receive an error,

> signaling: Can not access the backend.

Here are my different configuration files:

*config.yml*

```
ivory_ck_editor:
default_config: default
configs:
    default:
        filebrowserBrowseRoute: elfinder
        filebrowserBrowseRouteParameters: []

fm_elfinder:
#assets_path: / # default is /assets, this is where css/js elfinder files are
instances:
    default:
        locale: '%locale%' # defaults to current request locale
        editor: ckeditor # other options are tinymce, tinymce4, fm_tinymce, form, simple, custom
        #editor_template: custom template for your editor # default null
        #path_prefix: / # for setting custom assets path prefix, useful for non vhost configurations, i.e. http://127.0.0.1/mysite/
        #fullscreen: true|false # default is true, applies to simple and ckeditor editors
        #theme: smoothness # jquery theme, default is 'smoothness'
        include_assets: true # disable if you want to manage loading of javascript and css assets manually
        #visible_mime_types: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'] # only show these mime types, defaults to show all
        connector:
            #debug: true|false # defaults to false
            roots:       # at least one root must be defined, defines root filemanager directories
                uploads:
                    #show_hidden: true|false # defaults to false, hides dotfiles
                    driver: LocalFileSystem
                    path: upload
                    upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
                    upload_deny: ['all']
                    upload_max_size: 8M # also file upload sizes restricted in php.ini
                    attributes:
                        - { pattern: '/.*/', read: true, write: true, locked: true }
```

Thx for your help :)

Comment: Does the folder 'upload' exists in your /web ?